# Memory management for objects instantiated in argument list in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, instantiation

Will I get a memory leak if I instantiate objects in an argument list without using the new keyword? E.g. I have a tile class:

```
// tile.h (too small for implementation)
class Tile {
  public:
    enum Type {
        TYPE_NONE = 0,
        TYPE_NORMAL,
        TYPE_BLOCK
    };

    inline Tile(const int id, const Type type) : id_(id), type_(type) {};
    inline int id() const { return id_; };
    inline Type type() const { return type_; };

  private:
    int id_;
    Type type_;
};
```

Later I am loading some tiles specified in a text file:

```
// ...
int tile_id;
Tile::Type tile_type;
fscanf(file_handle, "%d:%d ", &tile_id, &tile_type);
tile_list_.push_back(Tile(tile_id, tile_type)); // this is the line of interest
// ...
```

This appears to work. `Tile(tile_id, tile_type)` is the part I am unsure of, I don't know whether it ends up in stack or heap. `tile_list_` is a `std::vector<Tile>` and I have so far assumed that it will handle the memory for the `Tile` objects I pass it. Is this correct?

Now I am looking at making a method elsewhere that can take a similarly instantiated object as an argument. How would this look in the argument list, and what must be done in the method and in the calling code to ensure there is no memory leak?

P.S. Any comments on code style are also welcome, and I have a feeling that Tile may be better as a struct so welcome commentary on this specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have a memory leak, and the object will be destroyed after the expression.

```
tile_list_.push_back(Tile(tile_id, tile_type));
```

A copy of it is inserted in the vector. *Theoretically*. In practice, copy elision will probably occur in this case, but that irrelevant, I'm just stating this for the completness of the answer.

In general, you can't have memory leaks if you don't use `new` or `malloc`, unless of course you use a poor library that allocates memory in the back-end and doesn't use RAII. But this isn't the case here, since you're using `std`.

Comment: So it sounds like if I wanted to have a method that takes a throw-away object, e.g. `rectangle` in the method `void Draw(Surface* surface, const Rect& rectangle) { /* do stuff but don't keep rectangle */ }` it would also be fine to call in the same way as `push_back` as the rectangle would be copied (or elided) to the method scope, and the memory cleaned up automatically at the end of the scope, right?

Comment: @DavidMason yes. Note that a temporary can only bind to a `const` reference, so this wouldn't work if the signature was with `Rect& rectangle` instead of `const Rect& rectangle`.

Comment: thanks. I was essentially just blindly copying the signature of `vector::push_back(const T& x)` so it's nice to know that the const is necessary.